# labels appearing off screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have multiple labels appearing randomly on my iPad screen. It's important that they're all completely visible. Therefore, I use the last 4 lines of **Position label code** below to try to ensure that the location of the labels will be well within the frame of the screen. However, even when I replaced 100 with 200 in this line

```
int width = self.view.frame.size.height - 200;
```

occasionally a label is only half on the screen or sometimes not visible at all. I know that if I manually position a button (my one and only button, the rest are labels) using these coordinates

```
 CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake( 0, 80, 100, 30 );
```

then it will not be hidden by the navigation bar (the view controller is embedded in a navigation). Therefore, I want to ensure, for example, that labels are positioned at least 80 points from the top. Wouldn't this code guarantee that?  Why not?

**Position label code**

```
        CustomLabel *customerlabel = [self customLabel] //custom Label class
        timer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 50);
        CGRect newFrame;
        newFrame= timer.frame;
        int width = self.view.frame.size.width - 200;
        int height = self.view.frame.size.height - 200;
        newFrame.origin.x = arc4random() % width;
        newFrame.origin.y = arc4random() % height;
```

Comment: What is the size of the frame to which you're adding the labels?

Comment: @Stonz2 I assumed the 'frame' was just the bounds of the ipad/iphone screen. It's not something I set explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are positioning `customerlabel` in random height between 0 and `height-200`, which means, it can also be located behind the navigation bar. Try using this snippet to make it start after the bar:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

(The `if` here is because `edgesForExtendedLayout` exist only since iOS7)

Another thing - if you want to force the labels to be at least `y = 80` like you button - you can call something like this:

```
newFrame.origin.y = 80 + arc4random() % (height-80);
```

Than you will get a number that is between `80` and `height`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

`newFrame.origin.x = arc4random() % width;
 newFrame.origin.y = (arc4random() % height) + 80;`

And subtract the additional 80 from the value of height to compensate.